# What OIDC allow users to exchange credentials for a token

Tags: azure, api, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I have a SPA secured with AAD B2C. The SPA talks to APIs also secured with AAD B2C. Right now, users can copy/paste the authorization header from Chrome to a tool like Postman and call APIs directly.

I'd like to make this step a little easier for users. I suspect there's a token grant flow that allows a user to call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` and exchange username and password for a bearer token.

I can't find a reference to any such flow. Can you point me in the right direction?

There are too many users for me to create a AppID/Secret for each one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by `users`. If they are just internal testers you can configure an [Azure resource owner password client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy) and testers can be given its client ID and secret, then post their own username and password to get tokens.

This flow can be convenient for testing, but is not recommended for production usage. Eg in [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/) it has been removed. So perhaps avoid adding such a client to the production stage of your deployment pipeline.